# ibatis value should be Integer but I get Hashmap

Tags: java, ibatis

I have a problem on retrieving data from DB.

This is my method from DAO

```
@MapKey("key")
public Map<String, Integer> getMeasurementsPerNode() throws SQLException;
```

There is mapper

```
<select id="getMeasurementsPerNode" resultType="hashmap">
    SELECT 
        w.wd_ip AS `key`,
        COUNT(m.id) AS `value` 
    FROM t_workers w
    LEFT JOIN t_measurements m ON w.id = m.worker_id AND m.measurement_timestamp <![CDATA[>]]> DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    WHERE w.active = 1
    AND w.worker_type_id = 1
    GROUP BY w.wd_ip 
    ORDER BY `value` DESC
</select>
```

My problem is when I want to use obtained value from map as Integer I get `ClassCastException` (`Hashmap` to `Integer`). Can you please help me.

This is loop where I use it:

```
protected Map<String, Integer> nodeMeasurementsCount = nodeMapper.getMeasurementsPerNode();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> nodeThread : nodeMeasurementsCount.entrySet()) {
    NodeRestartCounter nrc = new NodeRestartCounter();
    nrc.setNode(nodeThread.getKey());
    nrc.setMeasurementCount(nodeThread.getValue());
    nodeRestartCounterList.add(nrc);
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: can you show how you are converting map to Integer

Comment: Description updated. I googled out a lot, but I can't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: That's weird, if i replace your `nodeMeasurementsCount ` with a custom `HashMap<String, Integer>` that I populate with String/Integer pairs, there is no problem. Are you sure that the error comes from this part ?

Comment: Problem is when i want to set  nrc.setMeasurementCount(nodeThread.getValue()); i get exception. Btw field MeasurementCount is Integer, but nodeThread.getValue() returns {value=0, key=test}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do such kind of mapping.

The key and value in a Hashmap is contained in an Map.Entry object and cannot be directly mapped via SqlMaps.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

When you mention the result type as hashmap `(java.util.HashMap)`, the result is always a list of HashMap with each each map containing the column names as keys and their corresponding values as column values for a particular row.